# =SUM shows incorrect fraction

Tags: google-sheets

When doing a simple sum of cells in Google Sheets, the result is being reported as a fraction somehow? And the values make no sense? Does anyone know why this is happening?

In the pic below, you can see the values of the cells, the formula entered, and the preview of the result to the top left of the formula:

[image: pic]

Here's another one where summing 1,2 and 3 is reported as 1/5:

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this was caused by there being a date in the column to the left of this one and Sheets was treating this as a date despite the values themselves being decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The results you're seeing are not fractions. They are dates, counted from the Google Sheets origin date of December 30, 1899. So `=SUM(1,2,3)` would be 6, but you are seeing a date that is six days from that origin date instead (i.e., January 6, 1900; or, in short form, 1/6). Same with the other example you show, which is returning 2/21, because the total days from origin lands you on February 21, 1900.

Try just selecting the range with these outputs and setting the format to a number format instead of a date format: **Format > Number > Number**.